# Red5 connection doesn't close on client disconnect

Tags: red5

I've an application under Red5 1.0. 
After client connection lost server doesn't detect it and doesn't disconnect this client.
This code fixed a problem

```
    for(Set<IConnection> listConnection : connections) { 
        Iterator<IConnection> it = listConnection.iterator(); 
        while (it.hasNext()) { 
                IConnection con = it.next();
                ((IServiceCapableConnection)con).ping();
        } 
}   }
```

I just call this code once a 5 mins.

Have any idea why Red5 doesn't check it by itself?

Answer (score 1):

Check settings

```
rtmp.ping_interval=1000
rtmp.max_inactivity=5000
```

In the configuration file `/usr/local/red5/conf/` **`red5.properties`**